# ASP.Net applications with no authentication won't run on IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 to create an MVC application. I previously created one that used Windows Authentication, and in setting IIS Express 10 up for that, it seems to have stopped any sites with no authentication loading up. Instead I get the following error:

HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

I've Googled this error, and everything that comes back is for IIS, rather than the express version, which gives you very little in the way of managing it. I've looked in the configuration files in IIS Express and in my user folder for IIS Express, and anonymous authentication is enabled, so I'm really not sure what to do.

I've even tried re-installing IIS Express 10 to no avail, so any help would be appreciated, as I can't run a lot of MVC applications on my local machine at the moment.

Comment: please use Jexus Manager to review the settings and see if you get something wrong, http://jexusmanager.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up solving this myself by finding an answer from an unrelated problem. The anonymous authentication of the project itself was set to false. By enabling that in the properties window (which by default wasn't shown) the application ran again. So the answer to this is check that property is set correctly. I will try Jexus Manager too in the future, as it looks like the console that IIS Express is missing.